# jQuery count and echo child divs amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to count accordions child accordion amounts. I have several main accordions and they all have child accordions which can be removed and added (so the count changes). I would like to count the child accordions inside one main accordion and echo it in the title.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading main">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle main collapsed side-js" data-panel="02" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-panel" href="#panel-02">
                  <span>00</span>Category name 
                  <b>(0)</b>
                  <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
              </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="panel-02" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">/* Here are the sub accordions. */</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to paste the counted sub accordions ammount between  tags after the Category name text. Is it possible to automatically update it when sub accordions get removed or added?

### What I've tried so far

When adding a new sub accordion I tried to pass the new amount of sub accordions to the main accordion.

```
var findGroupNum = $('.accordion-toggle[data-panel="' + findGroupPlace + '"] > b').text();
var findGroupNumClean = findGroupNum.replace(/[\[(.)\]]/g, '');
findGroupNumClean++;
```

But this doesn't look like the best way to handle things.

I've also tried the `lengtht` method, but as far as I know it doesn't update when new sub accordions are added.

Comment: Did you happen to misspell length in your method as well?

Comment: I did mispell length method, but does it detect when a new accordion has been added or removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this easily by adding an id to your counter:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle main collapsed side-js" data-panel="02" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-panel" href="#panel-02">
                  <span>00</span>Category name 
                    <b>(<span id="cat-count">0</span>)</b>
                  <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
 </a>
```

and every time your user clicks an accordion; update the value like this (I'm assuming that you only have one `<a>` tag per accordion)

```
jQuery("#cat-count").html(jQuery("#panel-02 a").length)
```

the length property in this case is the length of a jQuery selection object and this *will* update as elements are added and removed.

_Pez

Comment: It works perfectly with some minor adjustments to fit my code. Thank You! :)